# Rename y-Values after loading them into chart?

Tags: vb.net, charts

this is my first question, so i hope i placed the question in the right way :)

I have got a problem with changing the y-Values.
Currently they have the numbers from 1 until 14.
Now i want to rename these values: e.g. instead of

`"1"->ID_a, "2"->ID_b` and so on

Has anyone an idea how to do that? I added the points with `]`

```
For Each row As DataRow In viewCIStateVerlauf2.Table.Rows
    Itemm = "ID" & row.Item("Item_ID")
    Select Case row.Item("State")
        Case "Change Completed                        "
            Series12.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))

        Case "Change Failed                           "
            Series11.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change Tested"
            Series10.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change Implemented                      "
            Series9.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change Accepted                         "
            Series8.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change Planned                          "
            Series7.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change Rejected                         "
            Series6.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change CCB_NOK                          "
            Series5.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change CCB_OK                           "
            Series4.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change Analyzed                         "
            Series3.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
        Case "Change New                              "
            Series2.Points.AddXY(row.Item("Snapshot_Date"), row.Item("Nummer"))
    End Select
    Series1.Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo), row.Item("Nummer"))
Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this :

```
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "First Point";
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[1].AxisLabel = "Second Point";
```

You can learn more on MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456628%28v=vs.100%29.aspx